# Unable to get Kafka message timestamp via Pyflink

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I have an incoming record from the Kafka source. It's in tuple format i.e. string. Non-json. By default, the record doesn't have any timestamp but I know for a fact that a timestamp is assigned by Kafka at the moment the record was written to the topic. Now, I am trying to get the timestamp of these records in `Pyflink 1.17.1` but as per the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#deserializer), `value-only` is supported as of now for Pyflink. Does it mean I can't implement a custom deserialization schema like `KafkaDeserializationSchema` for the `KafkaSource` class?

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74730866/pyflink-datastream-api-get-rowtimekafka-message-timestamp) SO post where there is a solution using the process function. That is the workaround I feel.

So, I was just wondering if I could implement some custom deserialization logic where I can get the timestamp of the record. I couldn't get any examples in the documentation. Should I change the class to `FlinkKafkaConsumer`(I know this is deprecated as of 1.17.1) or downgrade the Flink version?

Any references/lead is appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: The workaround with a process function seems like a pretty good solution. I would do that rather than use FlinkKafkaConsumer or downgrade Flink. Another solution would be to use the Table API, and then convert the table to a DataStream if you need a DataStream for some reason. (Why do you need to expose the timestamp? Maybe if you share the use case a better solution will come to mind.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DavidAnderson. I want the event timestamp because there would be a use case later on which I am aware of where we would have to do event time processing for the data. Therefore, was wondering about the efficient way of extracting the timestamp. Can I use the `watermarks strategy` as well?

Comment: I was able to implement the `process function` and it is working as expected but I am not sure why there is no support for `KafkaDeserializationSchema` for Pyflink.

Comment: The thing is, you can do most types of event time processing in Flink w/o extracting the timestamp, since windows and timers work just fine without that, since they depend on the timestamp that's already present in the StreamRecord wrapper. You can also implement a custom WatermarkStrategy without extracting the timestamp, so there's no obvious need to make this easier to do.

Comment: I suspect `KafkaDeserializationSchema` is missing simply because it's rarely needed, and you can always access the metadata and headers via the Table API if you really need them. My guess is that no one has gotten around to it yet, but I suppose there could be some technical impediment that I'm unaware of.

Comment: The process function approach is quite efficient; nothing to worry about there. As for using a watermark strategy, while the timestamp present in the record metadata is passed to the timestamp extractor as a parameter, you can't use that to modify the record payload, so it won't do you much good.

Comment: Cool. understood. Thanks for the clarification @DavidAnderson. Also, if you get a chance can you help me out with this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77220536/customdeserializer-not-working-for-accepting-string-as-tuples-in-pyflink thanks.