# CustomDeserializer not working for accepting string as tuples in pyflink

Tags: apache-flink, pyflink

I have incoming Kafka data which looks like `("field1", "field2")`. So, now I am trying to parse this input via `Pyflink 1.17.1` using a `custom deserializer` which looks like the below by referring [this](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.17/docs/connectors/datastream/kafka/#deserializer) link:

```
from pyflink.common import DeserializationSchema, Types, TypeInformation
from model.exceptions import SystemException

class StringToTupleDeserializationSchema(DeserializationSchema):
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def deserialize(self, message):
        parts = message.split(',')
        try:
            if len(parts) == 2:
                return (parts[0], parts[1])
        except Exception as e:
            raise SystemException(e)

    def get_produced_type(self):
        return TypeInformation.of((Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()))
```

Now, instead of `SimpleStringSchema()` I passed this Class as the input to KafkaSource as below:

```
source = KafkaSource.builder() \
            .set_bootstrap_servers("localhost:9092") \
            .set_topics("test-topic1") \
            .set_group_id("my-group") \
            .set_starting_offsets(KafkaOffsetsInitializer.latest()) \
            .set_value_only_deserializer(StringToTupleDeserializationSchema()) \
            .build()
ds = self.env.from_source(source, WatermarkStrategy.no_watermarks(), "Kafka Source")
```

But this raises an **error**:

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.fromSource.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.getProducedType(KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:56)
    at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.KafkaSource.getProducedType(KafkaSource.java:216)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.getTypeInfo(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2643)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.fromSource(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2015)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.api.python.shaded.py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I can get the elements I want using `string.strip` and `string.split` but that's not an efficient way to access the elements.

What am I missing here?

TIA

Comment: I have used `dataclasses` to map the input type to get the required tuple but still I want to achieve this using `CustomDeserializer` if possible. Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: I think getProducedType should be returning `Types.TUPLE(Types.STRING, Types.STRING)`.

Comment: Actually, `Tuple` expects only one argument and we are passing two arguments. So, it raises an error `py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o25.fromSource.
: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at org.apache.flink.connector.kafka.source.reader.deserializer.KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.getProducedType(KafkaValueOnlyDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:56)
` @DavidAnderson

Comment: @DavidAnderson I even tried returning the output of the `process` function I had developed since this `Deserializer` wasn't working. It works fine with `Types.TUPLE([Types.STRING(), Types.STRING(), Types.STRING()])` as the process function output but doesn't work with `get_produced_type`.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka messages are not string but bytes and they would have to be converted into string at the first place?

When you check `SimpleStringSchema` or `JsonRowDeserializationSchema`, they utilize the relevant JAVA class and I guess those classes converts byte into string internally.

I'd recommend to deserialize the values with `SimpleStringSchema` and apply a map function to split it into tuple.

[image]

Comment: Okay, yeah I know Kafka messages are in bytes but I am using `SimpleStringSchema` only I have used `ProcessAllWindowFunction` where I am actually splitting the string to tuple w.r.t datatype it possesses using DataClass. I guess that's fine too, right?

Comment: I was thinking of skipping this extra layer and implementing some custom deserializer which could be passed instead of SimpleStringSchema which will do the work for me but I guess this is not possible. @JaehyeonKim

Comment: Yes, I guess it won't be possible in Pyflink. I saw examples where Kafka messages are converted into POJO class in Java but such deserialization doesn't seem to be possible in Python.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the confirmation. I was stuck waiting for this clarity for days as I couldn't see any detailed explanation anywhere. @JaehyeonKim